# Regular Expression stuck

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression for the following string

```
abc.xy9.aBBB-hhh7.abcDD_XYz
```

That is,

- First character must be small letter
- Last character must be small letter/number
- in between `[A-Za-z0-9-_]` and a `.`

But the input string contains at least 3 and at most 63 character. Please check the below expression

```
^((\\.?([a-z]{1})([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)([a-z0-9]{1}))*){3,63}$
```

Comment: And what's the question and how is it related to C++?

Comment: Is it always 4 groups or should it be dynamic - also do you need capture groups for use afterwards, or is this purely a validation check

Comment: Yes, its dynamic but never exceed 63 char ,Ex: abc.ab9.aBBBt-gga.abb_fff9

Comment: @SmokeyPHP : Yes Its dynamic. but never exceed  63 chars
Example: abc.aGGGb974BBaa.yUd_gggT7.ab-yt78a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(([a-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]+[a-z0-9]\.)+[A-Za-z0-9_-]*[a-z0-9]|[a-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]+[a-z0-9])$
```

If it matches that, then check the length (e.g. in PHP check preg_match returns > 0, then check the total length with strlen).

I have assumed here from your example that each group is ending in lower case letter or number, not just the end of the whole string

Comment: I tried but couldn't figure out my expected behavior.Your assumption was right,a "." seperated by each word like "abc.ab9.aCCddF9.ayyyqTT_jj-a"

Comment: @Rono this expression works fine for me - what issue are you having?

Comment: Try aBBBa , its failed

Comment: Buddy thx for reply, try with aBBBa.a its also failed
This is enough ((([a-z]{1})([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)([a-z0-9]{1})\\.?)*), but its alos faile din aBBBa.a

Comment: @Rono Updated again! :D

Answer (score 1):

You already gave the description:

First character is a small letter: `[a-z]`
Last is a small lette or a number: `[a-z0-9]`
Inbetween:  [A-Za-z0-9-_.]

At least 3 characters, at most 63 means yu must repeat the middle regex 1 to 61 times.

Together:

```
[a-z][A-Za-z0-9_.-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]
```

However: You need something different from letters and digits that encloses your string. Without that, this regex *does* match, for example:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

This is because the regex can find 63 'a's and claim its a match.

Comment: Just being pedantic, but you might want to escape the last `-` in your expression.  Depending on how the regex is parsed, it could interpret the character class `9-_` which contains characters like `[]^`  Some parsers will work because it will ignore the 9, since it's in another character group, `0-9`, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: Thx bro "Ingo" for the reply. I have some more clarification in the query. That is; input string abc.xTTTT-jj-a.aHHH7 this is my expected input string its should be evaluated but its never exceeded 63 chars.Also the each word separated by "."

Comment: My expected string : a "." separated by each word Ex: "abc.ab9.aCCddF9.ayyyqTT_jj-a"

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. See, the `{3,63}` at the end is being applied to the regex as a whole - it would apply the entire regex 63 times. Instead, try placing that on your inner character class. Additionally, I don't think you want a period at the beginning, you want it in your character class, and saying `{1}` is redundant.

```
^((([a-z])([A-Za-z0-9_-.]{1,61})([a-z0-9])))$
```

Comment: Unless there's a need to capture groups, you can remove all of the parenthesis in this expression.  Even with the parenthesis, you have two sets of parenthesis on the outside, so you could remove one set and still capture the same groups.  Also, be careful of `-` inside a character class.  Your current expression is saying `_ through .` use `\-` in this case.

Comment: My expected string like this 
a "." separated by each word Ex: "abc.ab9.aCCddF9.ayyyqTT_jj-a"